# Firestore not reflecting changes in firestore after deployed

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, firebase-hosting

I have a web app written in [NUXT](https://nuxtjs.org/) that makes use of Firebase's Hosting, Firestore, Authentication and Storage.

Its a simple blog layout that has all the usual [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) functions for its blog posts. It is loosely bases on [Quick Nuxt.js SSR prototyping with Firebase Cloud Functions](https://medium.com/likecoin/quick-nuxt-js-ssr-prototyping-with-firebase-cloud-functions-5277553610a8) and [Nuxt.js Firebase Auth](https://github.com/davidroyer/nuxt-firebase-auth).

In the development environment it runs perfectly but when I deploy it, the Firestore specifically, behaves unexpectedly.

So after the project has been deployed I can CRUD documents that reflect as expected in the Firebase Console Firestore viewer, but when I read the data again it will load the same data. In other words if I delete a document it will disappear in the Firestore viewer but when I refresh my NUXT website it loads that document again even though it's no longer present in the Firebase console. I get the same result on different computers/devices, so not a local caching issue.

I noticed that the changes in the Firestore viewer will only reflect in my website after I re-deploy my project. But any changes I make will not show after I refresh the website even though they have changed permanently in the Firestore viewer.

When in development it works perfectly, I can manipulate the database, refresh and it will load exactly what’s reflected in Firestore viewer.

Sorry for repeating it so much but I’m having an existential crisis here, lol.

So below is a sample of the NUXT's Store's `index.js` file, where you would have all your data stored for your app. It works perfectly at manipulating the data on Firestore but once in production the website gets served the same data over and over.

```
import { firestore } from '~/plugins/fireinit.js' // the part where `firebase.initializeApp` happens
```

Decare my array state: posts.

```
export const state = () => ({
  posts: []
})
```

Mutations for manipulating the posts array.

```
export const mutations = {
  addP (state, payload) { // Gets run for each documents from collection on first load.
    state.posts.push(payload);
  },
  delP (state, payload) { // Deletes a post from the posts state.
    state.posts = state.posts.filter(p => {
      return p.id != payload.id;
    });
  },
}
```

The `nuxtServerInit()` runs on the server to make it Server Side Rendered when the website first loads.

```
export const actions = {
    async nuxtServerInit({commit}, context) {
        await firestore.collection('posts').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                var obj = doc.data()
                obj.id = doc.id;
                commit('posts/addP', obj)
            })
        })
    },
```

The `deletePost()` action deletes a file on Firebase Storage then deletes the document on Firestore. Then finally removes the item from the posts state.

```
    deletePost ({commit}, payload) {
      storage.ref().child(payload.fullPath).delete().then(function() {
        firestore.collection('posts').doc(payload.id).delete().then(()=>{
          commit('delP', payload);
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
          console.error(error);
        });
      })
    }
}
```

This is what my Firestore Rules look like

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong :/

Answer (score 3):

So after losing some hair I finally figured it out!

So in NUXT you have two options for deploying your project, `nuxt build` or `nuxt generate`.

The `generate` option reads the database and then builds your static files from the firestore, which is then deployed. This is why when I reloaded my page it had all the old entried in the DB.

After switching to the `build` option and deploying that instead it all works perfectly.